# FF throwing Strict-Transport-Security for my tomcat HTTPS

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, protocols

I have a webapp on Tomcat. I have a self-signed cert for testing SSL. Every call that I make, (get, ajax, css and javascript imports) Firefox is throwing:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: The connection to the site is untrustworthy, so the specified header was ignored.
```

Now I have added the exception to FF for my site, and I have a green lock symbol in the upper left of my browser. I know what HSTS is, but I'm pretty sure that I have not set that in any way. In the console, I see this in the response headers:

```
Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains"
```

So why is FF saying my site it untrustworthy, how did that header get in my response, and how do I make this error go away?

**UPDATE** 
  I have installed my self-signed cert into my jdk cacerts file.  I can connect to the site with HttpsURLConnection, and the request.isSecure()  returns true,  and request.getScheme() returns https,  BUT request.getProtocol() returns HTTP/1.1

Comment: Which tomcat version? did you uncomment the security filter shipped with tomcat?

Comment: 8.0.30  and I uncommented the httpHeaderSecurity filter and mapping, but that made no difference.

Comment: Do you connect to tomcat directly or through a reverse proxy (like apache or nginx...)?

Comment: Directly.  This is a development server on my laptop.

Comment: @mmaceachran did you find any solution to this? I am also facing the same.

Comment: @BilboBaggins No.  I got a new job and the problem went away. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application I wanted to run tomcat with https, and hence I followed steps mentions in this link: [HTTPS in Tomcat](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes).

Notice that it says to modify the web.xml, I just removed following from web.xml:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And the warning in Firefox is gone.

Further more in your case you might need to add following configuration:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>unchecked</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/webjars/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>   
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

In above configuration for all those urls which doesn't require a security constraints you need to add them to the `<url-pattern>` within the `<transport-gurantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>`. Hope it helps it helped me. here is a useful link: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security

Comment: I can't read tomcat xml, can you say what effect this has on the server responses so that I can port this answer to my particular implementation? I'm using nginx, if that helps answer my question -- how do I use this answer?